# Cannot get accurate counts out of pivot table in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an embedded query in excel that I've created a pivot table off of.  The data table outputs data in the following manner.

```
ID NUMBER   UNITS     DATE    ORDER NUMBER  VIN NUMBER
12345         3     1/6/2015    T000001     A123456789
12345         3     1/6/2015    T000001     A235874996
12345         3     1/6/2015    T000001     A879791235
54321         1     1/6/2015    T000002     A987955132
89654         1     1/6/2015    T000003     A188555175
25848         1     1/6/2015    T000004     A335813582
36985         3     1/7/2015    T000005     A321148785
36985         3     1/7/2015    T000005     A785116825
36985         3     1/7/2015    T000005     A897794651
78952         1     1/7/2015    T000006     A854168218
15936         1     1/7/2015    T000007     A874651358
48926         2     1/7/2015    T000008     A558746521
48926         2     1/7/2015    T000008     A688416521
26478         2     1/7/2015    T000009     A481612518
26478         2     1/7/2015    T000009     A153521684
55848         22    1/7/2015    T000010
```

I get multiple returns on the first column because there can be multiple unique VIN numbers in the last column the I need to see.  I've created a pivot table from this data with the Date, Order Number, ID number, and VIN number in "ROWS" section in that order.  I have Units in the "VALUES" section.  Everything works fine until I get to the last entry in the table with a unit count of 22. The pivot table defaults to count of units which works perfectly until I get to the last entry in the data which does not list unique VIN numbers but has a piece count of 22.  It only pulls a count of 1 into the pivot table.  I'm never going to get a unique list of VINS for situations like ID number 55848.  It will always appear like the data above.  Is there a way to modify the pivot table to accurately sum up the units with the same structure?

Comment: It sounds like you want counts for everything except for 55848, which you really just want to show 22 (which to return that in a Pivot Table you'd need to use Sum as the summary). That will always be an issue. you can't mix counts and sums in a single column in a pivot table. Alternatively, you could put `UNITS` in the `Values` section twice and summarize one by counts and the other by sums.

Comment: I'm getting 16 as the grand total for the data above, but want to get 37.  Guitarthrower hit the nail on the head.  That is the issue, but is there a way to get around it?  Sum gives me way wrong data.  It's counting each of the instances where units shows 3, 3 different times.  So the unit count for that ID number would be 9 instead of 3.

Comment: @pnuts that would be a manual process which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @pnuts I would prefer to do this in my raw data and create a new column to sum from.  However, I have no idea what type of formula I would use to only use the unit count once per ID# and to have that formula update upon refreshing the data.  Thoughts?

Comment: @pnuts that won't work since the ID number is always different.  It would have to determine if the ID number in the first column is unique and, if so, sum up the unit in that row only.